# jQuery dialog/javascript boolean not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-dialog

I have no idea if I'm doing this right but I'm trying to make it so when the delete Button is clicked a Dialog in my jQuery UI comes up

Comment: What `simpleDialog` library are you using? What exactly "isn't working"?

Comment: I'm only using the standard jquery libraries,  im trying to get it delete local storage upon click,  but no dialog even pops up and the code just redirects to the index main, nothing gets done.

Comment: So which "standard jquery libraries" do you mean? And what influences does your code come from? Did you look at documentation/tutorials to show you to use these methods/whatnot?

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot and forgot to put the src to the java file in my html, lolz. Thanks man.. I just fixed it.

Comment: Ok now that the OK part works, the cancel does nothing. When i click it , it just stays there and i cant get out of the dialog unless I click Okay, anyway to make it JUST close the dialog upon clicking cancel ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what `simpledialog` is - standard jQuery libraries don't have this feature. So unless you explain what that is, I couldn't tell you the syntax to close the dialog...

Comment: simpledialog is what I use, version1 only because on version2 I couldn't find the generator to generate one for me like I did with this one.

Comment: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/

Comment: upgraded to 2, found doc on it, says close is the command to close dialog but  how would I write that? i tried  this.dialog.close , and no luck

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `window.location.reload()` and then `return false` in your OK button's click handler, but anyways, to close a dialog, why aren't you using the syntax `$('element').simpledialog('close');`?

Comment: As for using `this`, put this line at the top of your `delegate` function's code: `var self = this;` and then use `self` anywhere else inside to refer to the dialog's element...where `this` refers to different things in other events.

Comment: Still learning jQuery heh, thanks a lot man.. not sure what you meant by your last comment.

Comment: Look at this page: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html - see at the bottom? How they use `self`?

Comment: Oh gotcha! thanks.. now to figure out how to make it so when they click Ok, another dialog I make will can pop up.

Comment: @HELTER you're reloading the page on 'OK' - you can't make another dialog popup at that point because you're no longer running the same script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding:

```
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
```

on the close